# How to delete cypress reports for both windows and linux before every run?

Tags: automated-testing, cypress, cross-browser-testing, linux

using below script for windows and linux but it is not working for linux
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Path separators in Linux and other unix-like OSes are `/` characters. You have it set up to use `\` characters. Just use one, because you probably won't have to escape it.